# Get acceleration from distance and speed

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

I want to know how fast an object with the speed **s1** (2.77m/s) would have to deccelarate to reach a speed **s2** (0m/s) within a certain distance **d** (2.35m). With a formula for that I could go on to calculate the time needed, the force applied and so on...

---

Given:

- Initial speed (2.77m/s)
- resulting speed (0m/s)
- distance to deccelarate (2.35m)

Searching:

- deccelaration

---

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Comment: Write down the relevant equations.

Comment: See [Equation 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line).

Comment: @David G. Stork edited OP

Comment: @Math Lover There are some interesting formulas there, but not the one I am looking for.

Comment: @Bruno Eq. 4 in the said link should solve your problem. You might look at some 'simple' forms of these equations beneath the first set of equations.

Comment: @Bruno:  You have NOT written down the equations.  Instead you wrote the values of *variables*.  An equation states mathematically how they are related.  Here is just one of your needed equations:  $x = v t + x_0$, i.e., the position $x$ is equation to the initial position $x_0$ plus the velocity times time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: You appear to be assuming constant acceleration. That needs to be made explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following formula, which can be rearranged easily.
$(v_2)^2 - (v_1)^2$ = $2ad$ $\Rightarrow$ $a$ = $\frac{(v_2)^2-(v_1)^2}{2d}$.
Since our deceleration leads to a final velocity of $0 \frac{m}{s}$, we can say $a$ = $\frac{-(v_1)^2}{2d}$.
$a$ = $\frac{-(2.77)^2}{2(2.35)}$ $\approx -1.63253 \frac{m}{s^2}$

Comment: How would I test if that result is correct? Can I just create a function f(x)=-1.63253x^2+2.77 and look at the interval from x=0 to y=0?

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy kinematics/physics problem. Your object movement is described by movement equations.

$s2=s1-a*t (1)$

$d = s1*t - \frac{a*t^2}{2} (2)$

where s1,s2 -velocity, t - time, a - deceleration, d-distance.

Because $S2=0$, so (1) can be rewritten

$s1=a*t => t=\frac{s1}{a}(1')$

put (1') to (2)

$d = \frac{s1^2}{a} - \frac{s1^2}{2*a} = \frac{s1^2}{2*a}(3)$

or

$a = \frac{s1^2}{2*d} = \frac{2.77^2}{2*2.35} = 1.6325 \frac{m}{s^2}$